# Unable to Create Bootable USB from Windows Vista ISO

Tags: usb, windows-vista, iso-image, bootable-media

I have this old laptop hanging around and I have Dreamsparks from my university account. I decided to try Windows Vista on this old laptop which currently has XP installed.

Currently I am unable to create a bootable USB from the ISO file and I have tried several tools and all of them are failing to create a bootable usb.

I tried with multiple USB device and enabled booting from USB. Depending on the burning software, I get different message, all in the line of not having a bootable OS on device.

Can anyone tell how I can resolve that.

Comment: In what way are they "failing" to make the bootable USB device?  Have you: Tried a different USB device?  Ensured booting to USB is enabled and configured in the BIOS?  Checked to see if the USB device will boot on a different/newer system?

Comment: @techie007 I tried with multiple USB device and enabled booting from USB. Depending on the burning software, I get different message, all in the line of not having a bootable OS on device.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue a couple times before, and the reason was that I had used the same USB stick for various OS installs (Windows, Linux, OSX) and the boot sector was a little.. well, off.

Finally the tool that solved all problems for me was [WiNToBootic](http://www.wintobootic.com/), but I'm not sure if it will support Vista, maybe only 7/8. Another tool you could try would be [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/), which gives you more options on how to format the drive.

Comment: I tried Rufus, it says the ISO format is not supported, not sure what it means.

Comment: WinToBootic also failed :(

Comment: Then it's probably a corrupt ISO image. Try redownloading or verifying the MD5 sum.

Comment: I can try downloading, but I am getting it directly from dreamspark. So should it be corrupted?

Comment: The Dreamspark downloader should check the ISO before finishing the download, but I generally don't trust any downloader programs. I'd retry.

Comment: It downloaded and did not give any warning, should i assume that the download is ok?

Comment: It should be OK, if I remember correctly the SecureDownloadManager application checks it automatically. If it still doesn't work, I don't know what could be wrong. Maybe try mounting it in [DaemonTools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/downloads)?

Comment: If it help, I extracted the files and tried running the setup from XP. I get a message saying the file is not a valid executable.